# Modifying a STYLE block in IE7 w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, styles, dhtml

I'm letting the user update the styling of their customizable widget by giving them an editable textarea with CSS code that updates a `<style>` element `onchange`.

JS:

```
function updateWidgetStyling() {
    $("#stylePreview").html( $('#WidgetviewCustomCSS').val() );
}
```

HTML:

```
<style id="stylePreview">
...
</style>

<textarea name="data[Widgetview][customCSS]" cols="30" rows="6" 
onchange="updateWidgetStyling()" id="WidgetviewCustomCSS">...</textarea>
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox, & IE9, but not in IE7.

Any idea how to get this working there? It's unfortunate, but we're a B2B and require IE7 support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i know it's hacky, but why not style the customizable widget(s) directly with inline CSS?

Comment: Because a stylesheet is easier for the user to read/update. The widget has a lot of CSS (~100 lines) and many classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the stylesheet, remove it from the DOM and insert a new one. This should trigger a full re-rendering of the page.